# Best way to access device_vector from C++

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, nvcc

I was wondering what the best way to access a thrust device_vector from host c++ code? I have written a cuda API to do basic vector algebra as I want to build an interpreter, similar to Matlab/Octave, where the vectors are stored on the GPU and can easily do computations like reduce, reduce_by_key, etc.

I was thinking of getting the raw pointer from an allocation of device_vector and storing it in a hash table with the associated variable name but was wondering if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in performance, you should not attempt to access a `thrust::device_vector` directly from host code.  Copy it to a host variable first.

If you do use a `device_vector` directly from host code, it is legal, but thrust will [generate a device->host copy operation](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) "under the hood" to enable this.  This will be very slow for wholesale data access.

Thrust raw pointers are not useful, since dereferencing these in host code will generate a seg fault.

Although not directly related to your question, you may find some interesting code in [newton](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/newton), a set of expression templates for thrust.